# Returning a List of entity objects from ajax

Tags: ajax, entity-framework, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am new to ajax and I am trying to return a list of entity objects via ajax. When  I do this with string it works successfully.

my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/MemberPages/AdminPages/AddProduct.aspx/GetList",
    data: '{"categoryId":' + $('#<%=ddlCategory.ClientID %> option:selected').val() +  '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        var cats = msg.d;
         $.each(cats, function (index, cat) {
             alert(cat);
         });
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

my code that returns a string:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<String> GetList(int categoryId)
{
        List<String> catlist = new List<String>();
        IQueryable<SubCategory> clist = new ProductsBL().GetSubCategories(categoryId);

        foreach (SubCategory c in clist)
        {
            catlist.Add(c.Name.ToString());
        }

        return catlist;
 }
```

my code that gives a 500 internal server error

```
 [WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public static List<SubCategory> GetList(int categoryId)
 {
        List<SubCategory> catlist = new List<SubCategory>();
        IQueryable<SubCategory> clist = new ProductsBL().GetSubCategories(categoryId);

        foreach (SubCategory c in clist)
        {
            catlist.Add(c);
        }

        return catlist;
 }
```

Thanks For any help as I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove the external quotes to the "data" in the jQuery call

```
data: {categoryId: $('#<%=ddlCategory.ClientID %> option:selected').val() },
```

Otherwise you submit a String, not the intended request composed by parameter called categoryId and valued as extracted from the selected option

Comment: I have tried the way that you have told me but it still gives me an internal server error.